# How to set vibration ON when getting e-mail (Gmail)?

Tags: gmail

Using Android 2.1-update1
It seems there's no "vibration" settings in the menu regarding this!

Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Menu > More > Settings`, make sure that "Email Notifications" is checked then "Select Ringtone > Silent" and "Vibrate > For All Gmail notifications".

Comment: Tip: In the settings screen, you must click on your account's name