# How to get warning if there is an e-mail?

Tags: notifications, gmail

I know how to set vibration when getting an e-mail: [How to set vibration ON when getting e-mail (Gmail)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9139/how-to-set-vibration-on-when-getting-e-mail-gmail)

But how can I set my Android phone to **always** vibrate/give sound when getting an e-mail?

I'm asking it because once I get an e-mail, my phone will stay silent, even if I get another e-mail. I need a feature/setting that enables this, to have a warning, when a message arrives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uncheck the "Notify Once" option in your GMail account settings and you should get a notification for every new message.

(Specifically: `Menu -> More -> Settings -> Notify Once`)

**Edit:** Apparently older versions of GMail do not have this option, in which case you would actually need to try a third-party app such as [GMail Notifier](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jonasl.gmailnotifier2&feature=search_result).

Comment: sorry for asking, but where is this "Specifically Menu" :D

Comment: I'm using Android 2.1-update1 and I can't find it. In the Gmail app I go to Settings -> and I can't find a "more" menu :O

Comment: @LanceBaynes: "More" is displayed when you press the menu button, not in the settings screen.

Comment: If I press the menu button then it says: Refresh/Compose/Accounts/View labels/Search/Settings

Comment: Then just select "Settings". The "Notify Once" option should be at the bottom of the settings, unless it was added after 2.1 (in which case you'd need an app like [GMail Notifier](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jonasl.gmailnotifier2&feature=search_result), I guess).

Comment: yep, it's not in this version: in the Notification settings there are: Email notifications, Select ringtone, Vibrate..

Comment: @LanceBaynes: Ah, definitely should be right at the bottom of that section. I added the GMail Notifier app to my answer since it looks like it is attempt to solve the problem on older Android versions. Must have been added at some point after 2.1...

Comment: i tried the gmail notifier out. it works perfectly. thank you!

Comment: I reseted my phone, and I can't find the "gmail notifier"??? - where is it?? was it trojaned or what??